# Link between Correspondance Analysis and MCA

Tags: visualization, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction

I've been dealing with a dataset full of categorical variables and had some issues to apply dimensionality reduction techniques as PCA is no great fit for such datasets.

After some research, I came across Multi Correspondence Aanalysis for the first time and read several documents about it, mainly this one (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.470.7630&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and they all talked about CA (Correspondence Analysis) since MCA is basically CA but when you have more than only two variables so I've been trying to read about that too.

The problem for me is when they say "MCA is simply CA applied to the indicator matrix"; I really can't understnd that statement. I understand it when they say that MCA is CA applied to the **Burt Matrix** and it makes sens for me, but when it's stated that MCA = CA + indicator matrix (see pages 3-4 in the document above for example), I can't see it.

Could anyone shed some light on that please ?

Thanks !